# How to forward to one of two overloads, without duplicating code?

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading, perfect-forwarding

I have a C++ class with two overloads of a private method, and those should be connected to two overloads of a public method.

The public method is the same in both overloads, it differs only in which overload of the private method it calls. The two private method overloads, on the other hand, are entirely different, which is why I chose to overload them in the first place.

To avoid duplicating code in the public method, this seems like a good use case for perfect forwarding. But on the other hand, then if you want to call the public method and are not familiar with the API, it's difficult to see which arguments you have to provide; you would have to examine the body of the public method, and then consult the private interface to see which overloads of the private method exist.

I've tried to make a toy class that illustrates my problem:

```
class Foo {
public:
    struct DontCopyTheBaz {};

private:
    bool init_from_baz(Baz& a_baz);
    bool init_from_baz(Baz& a_baz, DontCopyTheBaz);

public:
    // ...should I use perfect forwarding, making the API not easily readable?
    template<typename... Args>
    static Foo* new_for_baz(Baz& a_baz, Args&&... args) {
        Foo* the_foo = new Foo();
        if (!the_foo->init_from_baz(a_baz, std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
            delete the_foo;
            return nullptr;
        }
        return the_foo;
    }

    // ...or should I write duplicated code?
    static Foo* new_for_baz(Baz& a_baz) {
        Foo* the_foo = new Foo();
        if (!the_foo->init_from_baz(a_baz)) {
            delete the_foo;
            return nullptr;
        }
        return the_foo;
    }
    static Foo* new_for_baz(Baz& a_baz, DontCopyTheBaz no_copy) {
        Foo* the_foo = new Foo();
        if (!the_foo->init_from_baz(a_baz, no_copy)) {
            delete the_foo;
            return nullptr;
        }
        return the_foo;
    }
};
```

(In reality both the private and public methods are longer and more complicated.)

Is there a way to avoid the code duplication, while still making the API easy to understand?

Comment: Re: “you would have to examine the body of the public method…” Only if the documentation didn’t adequately explain how to use the class.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I disagree. If you look at the standard library as an example, in every case of a variadic template/perfect forwarding, you can use the available template parameters either on the function or the type to figure out what parameters are legal. `make_shared<T>` takes whatever the constructors of `T` take. `std::function<FuncType>::operator()` takes the parameters of `FuncType`. And so forth. If you just have a naked function like that, with no easily apparent meaning behind those parameters, the assumption is that the function will take anything, or anything fitting some concept.

Comment: Actually, I like your second version more. IMHO, it's easier to recognize what it does. Can't you prevent the code duplication by making them "trampolines" which both call the same private helper method?

Comment: @NicolBolas -- I'm quite familiar with the specification of the standard library. You don't have to root through the implementation to see what it does. Yes, the standard uses the **names** of template arguments to provide part of the specification; that's all clearly spelled out in the standard, i.e., **in the documentation**. And in some cases (although these are slowly being removed) the standard uses code as a specification of **behavior**, but it does **not** specify **requirements**.

Comment: @NicolBolas -- to make my original point more bluntly: if you have to read the code to figure out what the requirements are, the class designer has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extra indirection to factorize the code and have clean interface:

```
class Foo {
public:
    struct DontCopyTheBaz {};

private:
    bool init_from_baz(Baz& a_baz);
    bool init_from_baz(Baz& a_baz, DontCopyTheBaz);

    template<typename... Args>
    static std::unique_ptr<Foo> new_for_baz_impl(Baz& a_baz, Args&&... args) {
        auto the_foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
        if (!the_foo->init_from_baz(a_baz, std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        return the_foo;
    }

public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Foo> new_for_baz(Baz& a_baz) {
        return new_for_baz_impl(a_baz);
    }
    static std::unique_ptr<Foo> new_for_baz(Baz& a_baz, DontCopyTheBaz no_copy) {
        return new_for_baz_impl(a_baz, no_copy);
    }
};
```